# YUI TreeView Selection destroyed on recreate

Tags: javascript, treeview, yui

I have a YUI Treeview that allows selection with checkboxes.  After some operations, I destroy the tree (with tree.destroy()), and then create a new tree using the same containerID.  This new tree should allow selection using checkboxes, but does not.  What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got some code, that'd be helpful, but in general the `destroy` method cleans up the JavaScript side of things (listeners, etc.), but doesn't necessarily clean up all of the markup.  If you want to use the same ID, it'd consider removing that ID from the DOM to clean out all of it's children and then recreating it and then building the tree.  I'm guessing that's not super helpful, but maybe if you can explain your use case a little more, I can offer some better suggestions.